# Anaconda worker could not start because: connection to localhost timed out after 0.2s. tried to connect 7 > times during 2.0 seconds

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext3

I've just installed Anaconda by using Package Control; and, after installing it, the terminal show me this message:

> anacondaST3: ERROR - Anaconda worker could not start because:
>
> connection to localhost:50462 timed out after 0.2s. tried to connect 7
> times during 2.0 seconds
>
> check that there is Python process executing the anaconda
> jsonserver.py script running in your system. If there is, check that
> you can connect to your localhost writing the following script in your
> Sublime Text 3 console:
>
> import socket; socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
> socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect(("localhost", 50462))
>
> If anaconda works just fine after you received this error and the
> command above worked you can make anaconda to do not show you this
> error anymore setting the 'swallow_startup_errors' to 'true' in your
> configuration file.

And, the Anaconda autocompletation just doesn't work, the only reason I installed Anaconda for.

What should I do?
I'm practically a beginner in all of this programming stuff, so, be nice:(

Comment: See anaconda issue #527 [**<Anaconda.anaconda_lib.workers.local_worker.LocalWorker object > initial check failed**](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/issues/527)

Comment: answer in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849999/sublime-text-3-anaconda-package-error-connection-to-localhost-timed-out

Answer (score 9):

I come cross this problem When I use sublime3，
I fix it When I change the python_interpreter

I think you could change the default Anaconda Python interpreter from python to python3.
In the preference  > Package Settings > Anaconda > "Settings - Default"
you could  see and change this,from python to python3:
"python_interpreter": "python3", which is in line 100.

Comment: I tested changing the parameter in the project settings and it did not work in real time, I had to close sublime and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing complete path to your python interpreter (e.g. not "python_interpreter": "python3", but "python_interpreter": "/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python3").
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

By default, anaconda uses the python interpreter that is in your **PATH** environment variable, the most important configuration option is the python_interpreter option that allow the user to use a different python interpreter, for example, one that resides in a virtual environment:

```
{"python_interpreter": "~/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python older than version 3, then put the version of your Python in python_interpreter. I have it python312

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35616150)